# Design pattern for overcoming the reverse constructor order?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, constructor

**I have the following problem:**

The base class expects to receive some data but the data is initialized by the derived class constructor which in C# is called after the base constructor was called.

**Context / What I'm trying to solve:**

Let's call the base class `Track`, its role is to build a mesh that represents a track for a video game.

The derived classes, e.g. `Track1` each fetch track data from a particular file format, with significant differences that forbids implementing the whole code in base class `Track`.

The main job of `Track` is to abstract the data incoming from derived classes and for this it has abstract members that derived classes have to implement, e.g. `int GetVertexCount`, `Vector3 GetVertex(int)`.

Think more of less of it being an `IPicture` interface that can load from different formats, e.g. BMP, JPEG, and return the whole thing as an abstraction.

*The problem I am facing:*

In C#, base class constructors are called before derived class constructor, but I must initialize something in the *derived* class constructor that in turn I must pass to the *base* class constructor. And while I'm on it, I would like to have members to be immutable, i.e. `readonly`.

**Question:**

How can I run some code in derived class constructor first, so I can pass the result to the base constructor ?

**Answer:**

Following **@Kit** answer here's how I ended up doing and it's just fine:

[image]

Ironically, it ended up being a C-like API :)

Comment: You could create `abstract` or `virtual` method in `Base` class and invite it before `_s = s.ToLower()` and then override that method in `Derived`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough and updated my question, while indeed your method is interesting I won't be able to initialize `readonly` fields from the method.

Comment: Why do you need to process `_o` from ctor, just move the processing into that method and return it as a return value and use in `Base`...

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Just reworded the entire question, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: These classes shouldn't share a hierarchy with one another. Something that loads tracks is not a thing that is itself a track.  It should *produce* a track, not be the track that was loaded.

Comment: You've made point, that's right, they're totally unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need an instance of your derived class to do the logic you want, you can call a static method from your derived constructor prior to calling the base constructor.

Here is a simplistic example

```
public class Base
{
     protected Base(SomeType data)
     {
         // base logic using data
     }
}

public class DerivedOne : Base
{
    public DerivedOne(int some, string data) : base(DerivedLogic(some, data))
    {
        ...
    }

    private static SomeType DerivedLogic(int some, string data) => ...
}

public class DerivedTwo : Base
{
    public DerivedTwo (string moreStuff) : base(DerivedLogic(moreStuff))
    {
        ...
    }

    private static SomeType DerivedLogic(string moreStuff) => ...
}
```

This runs in the following order:

1. Static method `DerivedLogic`
2. Base class constructor (using the value from `DerivedLogic`)
3. Derived constructor

Now, that's slightly weird. What might be better is the derived logic not be a part of the derived class at all. What do I mean? I mean you have a third class that is passed into the derived constructor, and then on to the base constructor. That gives you the same effect.

```
public class Base
{
     protected Base(SomeOtherType dataWrapper)
     {
         var data = dataWrapper.DerivedLogic();
         // base logic using data
     }
}

public class DerivedOne : Base
{
    public DerivedOne(SomeOtherType otherType) : base(otherType)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or calculate `SomeType` somewhere prior to calling any constructors and then pass it in. Either of these ways is a better design because it follows [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):

1. Base class responsible for what it does.
2. Logic for constructing a track has that single responsibility.
3. Derived class has it's single responsibility.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with the following: `protected Track(ITrackBuilder builder)` then I inject a new instance of the appropriate type in derived classes. So basically I'll end up with a bunch of builders but in return the derived tracks are simply proxys that don't have any more code.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a really elegant way to do *exactly* what you're asking for, but I would question whether it's really necessary. It's usually a code smell to see logic in a constructor.

There are lots of other approaches you can take, like using a static `Create()` method.

```
class Derived : Base
{
    private readonly object _o;

    private Derived(object o, string s) : base(s)
    {
        _o = o;
    }

    public static Derived Create(string path)
    {
        var o = new object();// initialize from path
        var s = o.ToString(); // get s from o.
        return new Derived(o, s)
    }
}
```

You could also consider using composition over inheritance:

```
class Base
{
    private readonly string _s;

    public Base(string s)
    {
        _s = s.ToLower();
    }
}

class Derived
{
    private readonly object _o;
    private readonly Base _b;

    public Derived(string path)
    {
        _o = new object();// initialize from path
        _b = new Base(_o.ToString());
    }       
}
```

But it's really difficult to know which of these approaches might be appropriate without knowing what your actual goals and constraints are. You've told us *how you want to solve your problem*, and not *what problem you're trying to solve*.

Comment: Just updated my question to explain the problem in detail.